# Intellij Thymeleaf Syntax highlight not working properly

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I am using the ultimate edition and the following code is working fine. Issue is with bad highlights as you can see below. Been checking and doesn't look like I need an additional plugins for this. Is there a way around this?

I am using following line at the top of the html file's page.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

[image]

```
<div class="gifs container">
    <div class="row">
        <div th:each="gif : ${gifs}" class="col s12 l4">
            <a th:href="@{'/gif/' + ${gif.name}}">
                <img th:src="@{'/gifs/' + ${gif.name} + '.gif'}" />
                <a href="#" th:class="(${gif.favourite}? 'un':'') + 'mark favorite'"></a>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please [report a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with the [reproducible test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Issue raised: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170803#u=1491053261100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way that the Thymeleaf plugin can infer the type of the gifs and gif variables as there is no connection between the controller adding the model parameter and the template itself.
Thymeleaf integration in IntelliJ is working fine, indicated by the th: tags not being underlined :p

Answer (score 0):

I found that when you comment in the variable object it works.

For example:

```
<!--/*@thymesVar id="trackingNumberList" type="java.util.ArrayList"*/-->
<!--/*@thymesVar id="gif" type="com.myproject.mygifs"*/-->
```

Whether that can work for an Arraylist of a specific type is another question.